# UIViewController not responding to touches

Tags: iphone

Hey all, I'm completely stumped with this iPhone problem.

This is my first time building a view programmatically, without a nib. I can get the view displaying things just fine, but the darn ViewController isn't responding to touches the way it used to in programs where I used a nib. I should add that in the past, I started with the View-Based Application template, and this time I used the Window-Based Application template.

My thinking is that the View-Based template does something magical to let the iPhone know where to send the touch events, but I can't figure out what that would be even after several hours of bumbling around Google. Or I could be looking in an entirely wrong place and my troubles are related to something else entirely. Any thoughts?

Comment: please post some code, start with your overriding of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magical in the view-based template. The most likely reasons for failure to respond to touches are:

- You've messed with `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `userInteractionEnabled`, `exclusiveTouch` or something else, thinking you need to mess with these (generally you don't; the defaults are generally correct)
- You created a second UIWindow
- You put something over the view (even if it's transparent)

Simplify your code down to just creating a view programatically that responds to a touch and nothing else. It should be just a few lines of code. If you can't get that working, post the code and we'll look at what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. touche**s**Ended != touche**d**Ended.

That'll teach me to program without my glasses on.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible scenario for failure in response to touches is when your VC frame is not predefined and its boundaries are actually exceeding the window placeholder. 
 It happens a lot when you just forget to define the frame property for the VC.

Once you define it correctly - User interaction returns to normal.

Good luck !